# SpringTest DBUnit: Failed to Load Application Context cause by Unable to locate keycloak.json

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, spring-test, spring-test-mvc, spring-test-dbunit

Hi I am new to spring mvc and would like to create an integration test using spring test dbunit but I am encountering an error. Keycloak.json file was not found but it exists under the test folder. The path of keycloak.json is also indicated in the application.properties file. Please see error below.Thanks

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'keycloakPreAuthActionsFilter' defined in class path resource [com/projects/commons/security/SecurityConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adapterDeploymentContext' defined in class path resource [com/projects/commons/security/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterDeploymentContext]: Factory method 'adapterDeploymentContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to locate Keycloak configuration file: keycloak.json
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'keycloakPreAuthActionsFilter' defined in class path resource [com/projects/commons/security/SecurityConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adapterDeploymentContext' defined in class path resource [com/projects/commons/security/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterDeploymentContext]: Factory method 'adapterDeploymentContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to locate Keycloak configuration file: keycloak.json
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'keycloakPreAuthActionsFilter' defined in class path resource [com/projects/commons/security/SecurityConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adapterDeploymentContext' defined in class path resource [com/projects/commons/security/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterDeploymentContext]: Factory method 'adapterDeploymentContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to locate Keycloak configuration file: keycloak.json
.
.
.
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adapterDeploymentContext' defined in class path resource [com/projects/commons/security/SecurityConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterDeploymentContext]: Factory method 'adapterDeploymentContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to locate Keycloak configuration file: keycloak.json
```

Here is the BaseTestClass

```
//import classes

@Configuration
@ComponentScan( {"com.projects.person", "com.projects.commons"} )
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource( "classpath:application.properties" )
public class BaseTestConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private OperatingSystem operatingSystem;

    @Autowired
    private PropertiesFactory propertiesFactory;

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver()
    {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix( "/WEB-INF/pages/" );
        resolver.setSuffix( ".jsp" );
        resolver.setViewClass( JstlView.class );
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan( "com.projects.person.model.db" );
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        String databaseUrl = "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/persondb";
        if( operatingSystem.isWindows() )
        {
            databaseUrl = "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/persondb";
        }

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl( databaseUrl );
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public H2Connection dbUnitConnection() throws SQLException, DatabaseUnitException {
        return new H2Connection(dataSource().getConnection(), "Person");
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = propertiesFactory.createTransactionManagerProperty();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Here is Spring Test I created

```
//import classes

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {BaseTestConfig.class})
@TestExecutionListeners({
        DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        /*DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,*/
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
        DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class
})
@DbUnitConfiguration(databaseConnection = "dbUnitConnection")
@DatabaseSetup("classpath:dataset/empty-person.xml")
public class AddPersonTest {

    private static final String FIRSTNAME = "JANE";
    public static final String MIDDLENAME = "CRUZ";
    public static final String LASTNAME = "BILO";

    @Autowired
    private PersonController personController;

    @Autowired
    private Principals principals;

    private PersonDB person;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        person = new PersonDB();
        person.setFirstName(FIRSTNAME);
        person.setMiddleName(MIDDLENAME);
        person.setLastName(LASTNAME);

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initContext() {
        System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "dev");
        System.setProperty("keycloak.configurationFile", "keycloak.json");
    }

    @Test
    @ExpectedDatabase("classpath:dataset/add-person.xml")
    public void testCreatePersonInstance() throws CrossSiteScriptingException {
        BindingResult mockBindingResult = mock(BindingResult.class);
        when(mockBindingResult.hasErrors()).thenReturn(false);
        personController.addPerson(person, mockBindingResult, principals.create(USERNAME, USERNAME, TRIGGERUI));
    }
    @Bean
    public Principals myPrincipals() {
        return new Principals();
    }
}
```

H2 Data Set to be tested:

empty set:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <persons />
</dataset>
```

add person set:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <persons PERSON_ID="1" FIRSTNAME="JANE" MIDDLENAME="CRUZ" LASTNAME="BILO"/>
</dataset>
```

These are the dependecies declared in pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Person</groupId>
    <artifactId>Person</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>${version.release}.${version.additionalFeatures}-${version.batch}</version>

    <properties>
        <hibernate.version>4.2.0.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.21</mysql.connector.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <jersey.version>1.9</jersey.version>
        <powermock.version>1.6.4</powermock.version>
        <version.release>4</version.release>
        <version.additionalFeatures>0</version.additionalFeatures>
        <version.batch>1</version.batch>
        <version.milestone>I3</version.milestone>
        <version.bugFix>0</version.bugFix>
        <common-gui.version>0.0.0-SNAPSHOT-0</common-gui.version>
    </properties>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:.../trunk/Person/</connection>
        <url>.../trunk/Person/</url>
    </scm>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- SLF4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- DB related dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.176</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SPRING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Caching Supports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JERSEY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- APACHE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0-RC1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- CGLIB is required to process @Configuration classes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet API and JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- TEST -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test-mvc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.M1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nokia.care.common-gui</groupId>
            <artifactId>Commons</artifactId>
            <version>${common-gui.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- KEYCLOAK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-security-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${buildNumber}.${version.milestone}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <docheck>false</docheck>
                    <doupdate>false</doupdate>
                    <useLastCommittedRevision>true</useLastCommittedRevision>
                    <revisionOnScmFailure>unavailable</revisionOnScmFailure>
                    <providerImplementations>
                        <svn>javasvn</svn>
                    </providerImplementations>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.9</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>python</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>src/test/webapp/resources/grunt.py</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <id>grunt-build</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>                
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/dev.application.properties,WEB-INF/keycloak.json</packagingExcludes>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/pages</targetPath>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>Login.jsp</include>
                                <include>Banner.jsp</include>
                            </includes>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>html</format>
                        <format>xml</format>
                    </formats>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>jenkins</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>env.BUILD_NUMBER</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.7</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <formats>
                                    <format>xml</format>
                                </formats>
                            </configuration>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <phase>package</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>cobertura</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your Maven configuration, I can only assume that the file that cannot be found is `WEB-INF/keycloak.json` which does not reside in the root of the project.

Furthermore, I'll assume that your `WEB-INF` folder resides under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` within the root of your project, and that would explain why the file cannot be found with your current test configuration.

Based on my previous assumptions, the following should hopefully work for you.

```java
@BeforeClass
public static void initContext() {
    System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "dev");
    System.setProperty("keycloak.configurationFile", "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/keycloak.json");
}
```

Comment: In my case, I moved the keycloak.json file to `src/main/resources`, and used `System.setProperty("keycloak.configurationFile", "classpath:/keycloak.json");`